# Wordpress shortcode is not called

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Okay, I have created a plugin and now want to provide shortcode to app.
Here is my only file in `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Latest Issue
 * Author: Max Tsepkov
 * Author URI: http://www.yogi.pw
 */

add_action('init', function() {
    add_shortcode('my-plugin', function() {
        // ... my code

        return 'string';
    });
});
```

I know that plugin is activated and the callback for `init` is called.
But the shortcode function is never get called.
I add text `[my-plugin]` to a widget, and it isn't replaced as well.

What do I do wrong? How to correctly register a shortcode?

Comment: which version of PHP do you have?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Shortcode API in the codex. Also, by default, the text widget does not support shortcodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out, that some themes are not parsing shortcodes in widgets.
We can explicitly hook into theme filter and let it run shortcodes in widgets.
For details see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-shortcodes-work-in-a-widget

And there is no need for hook into init action. This code works:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Latest Issue
 * Author: Max Tsepkov
 * Author URI: http://www.yogi.pw
 */

// Allow theme to parse shortcodes in widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

add_shortcode('my-plugin', function() {
    // ... my code

    return 'string';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you PHP is at least 5.3, so you can make it work in a widget, you need to add this code.

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

I tested your code and it works.

Comment: Can I place this line in the plugin? I patched theme for now.